# Why don't we use single member function for set and get the data member value instead of separate accessor/getter and mutator/setter function?

Tags: c++, class, oop, accessor, mutators

I just have a really quick question as I am trying to grasp C++ class concept. Why don't we use a single member function for set and get the data member value instead of separate accessor/getter and mutator/setter function?

Example Shown Below:

```
class Student
{
    private: 
            int rollno;
    public:     
            int setGetRollNo(int rn) {
                rollno = rn;
                return rollno;
            }
        
};


int main()
{   
    Student s1;
    cout << s1.setGetRollNo(123);

    
}
```

It works the same as when we try to do that we sperate the accessor and mutator function.

Comment: What if you want to get `rollno` without changing it?

Comment: @Loocid sorry but I didn't get your point. Could you please explain this with an example?  I'm newbie in C++

Comment: What if I wanted to get the _current value_ of `rollno` without changing it to some new value? Right now, your `setGetRollNo(123)` overwrites whatever is currently in there with `123` and then returns the new value. What if I want to look, but not touch?

Comment: `const correctness` is a really nice feature of C++, in that it allows the compiler to help you avoid bugs by raising an error at compile-time if you code is trying to modify an object it shouldn't be trying to modify.  But if your `getter` is also a `setter`, then your `getter`can't be tagged as `const`, and therefore you won't be able to call it via a `const Student &` or via a `const Student *`, which means you'd have to pass non-const pointers/references around instead, making your code more fragile.

Comment: In your example, you've set `rollno` to 123. What if later in the program you want to print that students `rollno` again without changing it. How are you going to do that with your code?

Comment: Let's talk embedded systems.  There are some entities that are read-only.  They may generate an error when written to.  For example Flash Memory (without unlocking the programming cycle).  Other devices are write-only and can't be read from.  Most LEDs are wired to be write-only.  If you want to read, using your suggestion, then you will have to maintain the state of the member variable, so that you can set the state to the same value you read.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with having a function that can both access and mutate a member. However, the way you are doing is definitely incorrect. With the code you have right now, you cannot get the current value without setting it to a new value first.

Instead, a better way to do this is to do this is to return the reference of the member object:

```cpp
class Student
{
    int rollno;
public:
    int& rollno_ref()
    {
        return rollno;
    }
};
```

Now you can use the same function both access and mutate the member like:

```cpp
std::cout << student.rollno_ref();       // access
student.rollno_ref() = 10;               // mutate
```

---

One thing to note is that this function really doesn't do much beside exposing a reference to an existing member. To add more functionalities to it, you should look up proxy class.

---

Another thing to note is this function will not work on `const Student`. To make it work, you should supply its const version as well.

Comment: What's the point of this compared to just making `rollno` a `public` member?